# "Begin" or "Beginning"... which one should be used?

Tags: lyrics, word-in-context

The text bellow is part of the lyrics of a song from a Brazilian singer called Raul Seixas - The name of the song is "How could I know":

"Reformulation, rearrange the game you're in

Let us start from the begin

With confidence you'll win

That's the reason you were born"

The correct here wouldn't be to use "Let us start from the beginning" instead of "Let us start from the begin"? Or are both forms acceptable?

Comment: "Let us start from the begin" is not grammatical in any variety of English as far as I know.

Comment: @ColinFine That could be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let us start from the begin" is definitely not correct English. 'Begin' is a verb, and is being treated as a noun here. It should be "Let us start from the beginning".

That said, song lyrics often break the rules of grammar in order to satisfy metre (rhythm) and rhyme. This is even more true of songs translated from another language.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot. By the way, the song in question was a big hit in Brazil in the 70's and it's still very popular here. It was originally released in English and there was never a Portuguese version of it. Curiously, I never saw any comment about this English "mistake". Thanks again for your help.